# How to break a line into next line if it cross the column of length of 3000 in python

Tags: python, line-breaks

Well am trying to write a list of query into file using python. But I need to break the query length in a way if it cross more than 3000 col size.

```
 def write_sql(self,queries):
        with open(file, 'w') as f:
            queries = map(lambda x: x + '\n', queries)
            f.writelines(queries)
```

May I know how to modify this code to perform the requirement

Comment: if len(queries) >= 3000 ??

Comment: So `queries` is list of strings and each string should be broken to lines of maximal length of 3000?

Comment: Yes we need to break them into next line

Comment: look at textwrap module, it could help you: https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html